# Calculate element height in directive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Why is `nextTick` required in my example below in order to calculate the element height? As far as I know, `nextTick` is used to wait for DOM updates after reactive data has been modified, which is not the case below:

```
Vue.directive('test', {
    bind: function(el) {
    console.log($(el).css('height'))
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        console.log($(el).css('height'))
    })
  }
});

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo'
})
```

```
<div id="demo">
  <div v-test>
    lorem
    lorem
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPfpS/463/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong hook.

> **Hook Functions** A directive definition object can provide several hook
>   functions (all optional):
>
> 1. bind: called only once, when the directive is first bound to the
>      element. This is where you can do one-time setup work.
> 2. inserted: called when the bound element has been inserted into its
>      parent node (this only guarantees parent node presence, not
>      necessarily in-document).

```
Vue.directive('test', {
    inserted: function(el) {
    console.log($(el).css('height'))

  }
});

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo'
})
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43u7tf5m/)

Comment: Will do as soon as it's possible :)